# Transaction Retention Information

Tags: sql-server

If I right click on the properties of a replication article, I can get the transaction retention information.  This is useful *ONLY* if I have very few replication articles.  What table/view allows me to access this information, so that I can quickly do this without the GUI?

Thanks!

It's `distribution.dbo.MSpublications`.

Comment: you can use `exec distribution.dbo.sp_replmonitorhelppublication` --> `retention` column.